# Stationary probabilities of markov chain

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

I am confused in which conditions the stationary probabilities of both discrete and continuous Markov chain donot exist.

If it is due to periodic chain then is it for both discrete and continuous.

and one thing more the sum of row of the transition matrix of both discrete or continuous both is 1 or only discrete.

Comment: Which textbook are you following?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a continuous MC values in the $Q$ matrix are rates: usually $\lambda$ for going to the next state, $\mu$ to the previous state, and the diagonal value is $-(\lambda+
\mu)$, so they sum to 0.

From this you can obtain a jump matrix by standardizing: divide every row by $\lambda +\mu$ and set the diagonal value to 0 (hence 'jump'). Then row values will sum to 1.

Comment: if jump is λ from one node then how the equation that sum of all output transitions is one can fulfil in birth death chain and one thing more my second question is that :
"in which conditions the stationary probabilities of both discrete and continuous Markov chain donot exist.

If it is due to periodic chain then is it for both discrete and continuous."